# What is the name of this music instrument?

Tags: harmony, melody

I want to know which instrument is it for the music of raymans especially this

at the beggining, this who do the main melody ... a violin ? A midi synth in a computer music soft ?

Comment: It's some kind of synthesized "string instrument" imitation. I suspect it'll be hard to be more specific than that.